# Why is the law of conservation of energy violated here?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics, momentum, energy-conservation

The question comes from a very low grade class but confuses me
See image:

[image]

As we can see the total Kinetic Energy in the System before was 100Joule Which after Collison is only $200/3$Joule

Why is the law of Energy Broken Down here?

Answer (score 1):

If the objects are combined after collision, then we are dealing with a non-elastic collision. Then mechanical energy is not conserved.

Energy *is* conserved. Always. The energy conservation always holds true. Some energy is just "lost" within the materials during the collision, for instance energy spent in deforming and adhering the objects together (via glue? Velcro? Deforming?). In fully elastic collisions, such as two billiard balls colliding, they will never stay together after impact.

Such internal energy is hard to keep track of, making the energy conservation law basically impossible to use for simulation, prediction and calculation without much more data. This is why the momentum conservation law is very, very useful to have at hand when dealing with collisions.

Comment: You mean to say that the energy is absorbed my material to increase its temperature and for deformation

Comment: @Spidy Yes. Depending on your method of attaching the objects together, energy may also be lost in chemical bonds, micromechanically as work and similar.

Comment: You mean that exactly $100/3$ Joule is lost in Deformation or increase in their temperature

Comment: Wait Steeven I'll ask a different question where there is no combination of objects but before that question i want you to tell me - Can i say that in some situations a light object can collide with a heavy object to get completely stopped and that heavy object starts moving which was initially at rest?

Comment: @Spidy "*You mean that exactly 100/3 Joule is lost in Deformation or increase in their temperature*" Yes. With the data you have provided, yes.

Comment: @Spidy "*Can i say that in some situations a light object can collide with heay objects to get completely stopped and that heavy object starts moving which was initially at rest?*" This might not be possible with an elastic collision, no. You will need to interfere to stop the light object and thus provide an external interaction. To achieve a scenario where one object stops entirely, you will in general need two objects of equal mass with one being at rest initially.

Comment: Ok next question coming soon or later i don't know but I'll see you then

Comment: @Spidy You can simply ask your further questions as actual questions on the site, and then many more will be able to answer.